# Animation is not stop when panning in UWP

Tags: c#, animation, uwp

I have a two `Panel` both the `Panel` are in different `ScrollViewer`, I need to process the synchronous scrolling without animation, if I scrolled the second `Panel` the first `Panel`also need to scroll with same `HorizontalOffset` without animation.
I have used the `ViewChaning` event of 2nd `ScrollViewer` and update the view of 1st `ScrollViewer` with the same `HorizontalOffset`, without animation.
Its works perfectly when I scrolled using mouse, if I scroll using touch(panning) the animation is occurs.
Please refer the code below,

```
   private void ScrollViewer2_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.scrollViewer1.ChangeView(e.NextView.HorizontalOffset, e.NextView.VerticalOffset, null, true);
    }
```

How can I resole this issue, any one suggest on this?

Comment: What animation are you talking about? The one when `ScrollViewer` reach the boundaries on mobile? Could you please provide a gif image to show us?

Comment: When we change the view the frame work process some animation, we can able to disable the animation in ChangeView method of ScrollViewer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview , I have set this as true. Its works perfectly when i scroll the panel using mouse, If I scroll using touch its not works, all are in desktop alone, I have a touch monitor.